# How to Export multiple header Gridview Data to Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have a gridview which has multiple headers added during run time as shown in snap below:
[image]

I want to export the data from this gridview to excel for which I have the following code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            gdView.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White;
            foreach (TableCell hcell in gdView.HeaderRow.Cells)
            {
                hcell.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
            foreach (GridViewRow row in gdView.Rows)
            {
                {
                    row.BackColor = Color.White;
                    foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
                    {
                        cell.CssClass = "textmode";
                    }
                }
            }
            gdView.RenderControl(hw);
            //style to format numbers to string
            string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
            Response.Write(style);
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(System.Web.UI.Control control)
    {
        // controller   
    }
```

The excel output I am getting is as follows:

[image]

As you can see the color of the header rows is continuing beyond the table area. Also the top header rows are collapsed in the excel output.

Request you all to kindly suggest how this can be resolved.

Thanks.

Comment: Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/epplus/drafts/98280) for example. All you are doing now is creating a HTML page with an .xls extension.

Answer (score 0):

I could finally solve the issue by modifying the code as below:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            for (int x = 0; x <= 3; x++)
            {
                GridViewRow rows = (GridViewRow)gdView.HeaderRow.Parent.Controls[x];
                rows.BackColor = Color.White;
                rows.Height = 15;
                for (int i = 0; i <= rows.Cells.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    rows.Cells[i].BackColor = Color.Maroon;
                }
            } 
            foreach (GridViewRow row in gdView.Rows)
            {
                row.BackColor = Color.White;
                foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    cell.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Middle;
                    cell.CssClass = "textmode";
                }
            }
            gdView.RenderControl(hw);
            //style to format numbers to string
            string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
            Response.Write(style);
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(System.Web.UI.Control control)
    {
        // controller   
    }
```